# Unable to create course via api

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am trying to create a course in a semester through the api in valence d2l. I keep  getting a `404 not found` error, both in my program and in the "getting started" application. The call I am making is to `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/courses/` using post. I pass the following JSON object along with it:

```
{
    "Name": "COMM291 - Test A",
    "Code": "C-COMM291",
    "Path": "/enforced/C-COMM291/",
    "CourseTemplateId": 20992,
    "SemesterId": 20993,
    "StartDate": "2013-08-22T19:41:14.0983532Z",
    "EndDate": "2013-08-27T19:41:14.0993532Z",
    "LocaleId": 4105,
    "ForceLocale": false,
    "ShowAddressBook": false
}
```

I have also tried passing `null` for the fields that say they accept null values, but no luck. The course template and the semester ID are correct - I have tripled checked that they exist, I am enrolled in them and I am using the correct ID numbers.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that your path needs to start with `/content/` or `/shared/` or you will get a 400 status code back.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it still gave a 400 error. I have created course templates through the api as well and /content/ wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that part of my problem was with the call if I change it to /d2l/api/lp/1.3/courses/ instead of 1.0 it works, (1.0 will work but it seems that you can only pass null for the semester). 
The dates were also picky and did prefer milliseconds to only 3 decimal places.
Then passing null for LocaleId also helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the precision in your start and end dates to three decimals after the final point (e.g., `"2013-08-22T19:41:14.0983532Z"` becomes `"2013-08-22T19:41:14.098Z"`).

Comment: tried this but it resulted in a "bad request". thanks for the ideas

Comment: The format for UTCDateTimes is quite specific and fincky. Three decimals of precision, exactly, is required (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/conventions.html, bottom of page). If you're getting a 400, then something else about the JSON packet is badly formed (assuming the rest of the timestamp is well formed). I suggest not providing a content path at all -- provide an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If your org is configured to automatically enforce, and generate, paths for course offerings, then you should not provide one in your `CreateCourseOffering` block at all. The following structure works on our test instance: notice the empty string for path (shouldn't be null, but an empty string, I believe):

```
{ "Name": "Extensibility 104", 
  "Code": "EXT-104", 
  "Path": "", 
  "CourseTemplateId": 8082, 
  "SemesterId": 6984, 
  "StartDate": "2013-09-01T19:41:14.098Z", 
  "EndDate": "2013-12-27T19:41:14.098Z",
  "LocaleId": 1, 
  "ForceLocale": false, 
  "ShowAddressBook": false }
```

The other thing to note is that if your CreateCourse form doesn't have a form element to provide a Semester ID, then your API call should pass null for that property.

Comment: I copied and pasted your sample code into the getting started project, changed the coursetemplateId and the semesterId to ones in my system and it gives me an error of Unknown: BAD_REQUEST. I have verified my courseTemplate Id is correct and my semester Id.

Comment: My apologies -- my original example block was the original Python dictionary that I turned into JSON; I have since edited it so that it now uses real JSON syntax. There are several differences between them that would be important (use of quotes, the way `true` and `false` are written).